# Python List. Finding the maximum row with all elements not zero

Tags: python, list, numpy, max

I have a python list which looks a little like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,90,1,9999,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0],[0,0,90,1,9999,1,2,0,0,9999,0,0,00,0].....till about 30 rows]
```

I need to find the maximum row from this list which has a 9999 or in other words, which does not have all elements zero. Please help me with this. Thanks!!

I tried:

```
print max((numpy.where(v1==9999)[0]))
```

but this just gave me some weird errors like `'int' object not iterable` or `numpy.where does not accept keywords n` and so on!!

Comment: I am loath to attempt a solution as I think that you haven't been able to express what you need clearly. And when you do express your question so that it can be understood then the solution would be straight-forward.

Comment: Your conditions are ambiguous: "which has a 9999" and/or "which does not have all elements zero"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    python 3.2

    #   if you want to find how many rows in your list has 9999
    v=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,90,1,9999,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00,0]]

    len([i for i in v if 9999 in i])




 #   if any element in your rows is 9999 then all the elements of that row 
 # cannot be 0. then if you want to know how many rows have all the elements 0.


     len([i for i in v if sum(i)==0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want:

```
idx,row = max(enumerate(lst),key=lambda r: ( sum(r[1])==0, r[0] ) )
```

where `lst` is your list.

Or do you want:

```
next(x for x in reversed(lst) if sum(x) != 0)
```

Comment: I don't think so...

The max function has to essentially find the row with the highest index that does not have a sum==0.

Comment: @gran_profaci -- you need to be more clear about what your criteria is for the maximum row.

Comment: Yes, "maximum" usually refers to the highest value; the highest index (the "last" qualifying item) is a separate concept.

Comment: So, as you may notice, the rows have either all zeros or have some non-zero values. I need to find the row with the highest index that does not have sum(row)==zero. So, the row that is printed has to be the highest non-zero row. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Indeed, I apologize. I have to find the highest index value i.e. the row with the highest index that has a non-zero value.

Comment: @mgilson: It makes more sense to use any() that sum() since it will exit at the first non-zero value in the sublist rather than requiring it to sum all elements. See my answer for a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the indices that have non-"all-zero" rows:

```
nonzerorows = [i for i,j in enumerate(a) if any(j)]
```

And the highest index of such rows:

```
maxnonzerorows = max([i for i,j in enumerate(a) if any(j)])
```